# rabbitmq-server fails to start after hostname has changed for first time

Tags: ubuntu, rabbitmq, django-celery

I am using django-celery for my django project. Last day I have changed my computer's hostname (I am using Ubuntu 12.04, edited file '/etc/hostname'), and after next restart django-celery was failing with error

```
Consumer: Connection Error: [Errno 111] Connection refused. Trying again in 4 seconds...
```

After some research on this error I could find that, changing my host name caused this error from [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rabbitmq-server/+bug/653405). My rabbitmq startup log shows

file: /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_log

```
Activating RabbitMQ plugins ...

********************************************************************************
********************************************************************************

0 plugins activated:

ERROR: epmd error for host "jinesh": nxdomain (non-existing domain)
```

My startup_err file is empty.

when I run

```
root@jinesh:/home/jinesh# rabbitmqctl list_users
Listing users ...
Error: unable to connect to node rabbit@jinesh: nodedown

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

nodes in question: [rabbit@jinesh]

hosts, their running nodes and ports:
- unable to connect to epmd on jinesh: nxdomain

current node details:
- node name: rabbitmqctl4956@jinesh
- home dir: /var/lib/rabbitmq
- cookie hash: RGhmB2JR1LbZ57j7xWWTxg==
```

I hope changing the nodename may fix this issue. But I couldn't found a way to do this. Anyone have idea about how solve this issue?

**update**

while changing hostname you have to change both `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts` files.

I reinstalled rabbitmq and solved this issue, Will answer this question.

Comment: On centos/rhel, if you rename your network interfaces via /etc/udev/rules/70-persistant-net.rules and reboot --> doing so will also cause you to get an error message from `rabbitmqctl status` "unable to connect to epmd". --> The fix is the same as [the accepted answer by @RichardHFung for this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14659335/rabbitmq-server-fails-to-start-after-hostname-has-changed-for-first-time/16973026#16973026).

Comment: "systemctl restart rabbitmq-server.service" solved the same issue I had.

Comment: If on Ubuntu 16.04 or 18.04, do NOT install RabbitMQ via the repository (they're outdated). Head here https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html and save yourself some headache down the line, by installing both Erlang and RabbitMQ from one of the proposed repositories. I had a while ago installed Erlang from erlang solutions and had much later installed RabbitMQ via its Ubuntu repo and it originally worked without fuss. After a recent upgrade something went wrong and I spent 5 hours trying to fix it to no avail. I removed both packages and reinstalled Bintray's versions as explained. Fixed.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Remove the old installation of RabbitMQ to fix this problem. Here are steps to reinstall RabbitMQ. These commands are run as the root user:

1. Stop RabbitMQ: `rabbitmqctl stop`
2. Change `/etc/hosts`
3. Change `/etc/hostname`
4. Uninstall old RabbitMQ: `dpkg -P rabbitmq-server`
5. Remove RabbitMQ’s database: `rm -rf /var/lib/rabbitmq`
6. Find erlang’s process that is running rabbit: `ps ax | grep rabbit`
7. Kill the listed process
8. Reinstall RabbitMQ: `apt-get install rabbitmq-server`

I wrote about these steps on [my blog](http://www.techsfo.com/blog/2013/06/rabbitmq-breaks-when-you-rename-hostname/).

**REVISION**

I moved my blog to a new website.

Comment: Note that I didn't have to stop rabbit (because it wasn't running) or remove the `/var/lib/rabbitmq` folder (because it wasn't there); YMMV.

Comment: on ubuntu (14.04.1 LTS) this did not work for me.  I needed to `apt-get purge rabbitmq-server` and then run `apt-get install rabbitmq-server` to get it all working again after a hostname change.

Comment: RabbitMQ breaks for no good reason, and the only way to fix it is to uninstall and reinstall?This is alarming...

Comment: Neither the manual instructions nor the `apt-get` instructions worked for me. As of yet, still no solution. Is this an erlang problem?

Comment: Anyway of doing this without losing data?

Comment: my problem was that there was an erlang process running, killed it and rabbit started as normal.

Comment: i gave downvote because of solution is not a real solution. what if i change hostname again? remove rabbit again, install again ....

Comment: Check @Kishor Pawar answer if you don't want to lose data

Answer (score 43):

Thanks to Richard H Fung.

> **His steps helped me to solve this issue.**
>
> **But I did not have to re-install the rabbitmq**.

When I opened my `/etc/hosts` file I found that `IP` assigned to my hostname is different than the actual `ip(192.168.1.200 [static])`.

```
#/etc/hosts  
127.0.0.1       localhost  
192.168.1.115   HOSTNAME
```

so I just changed **IP address** to `192.168.1.200` in my `/etc/hosts` file and it worked fine.

Comment: this is the exact situation i had and same solution worked - no need to reinstall and fixed ip and worked

Comment: This should be accepted as the correct solution. On xenial I had /etc/hosts associating a GloballyRoutableIP with the `hostname` name (not fqdn), and found that associating the NetworkTenIP with that name repaired epmd. Killing epmd and restarting rabbit sufficed.

Comment: Phew! Didn't have to re-install either.  My issue after changing the hostname was that I don't use a FQDN in /etc/hostname.  This is OK, but you then need to put that short alias in `/etc/hosts` for 127.0.0.1 or the erlang system can't resolve it.   *I did however loose all queue contents*, presumably that store is associated with the old hostname.  Possibly this could be solved by putting an IP address in the conf file...

Answer (score 27):

Richard's answer is good, but you might lose some information in the rabbitmq queues. The following is a possible way to preserve the previous setup of rabbitmq with the new host name.

**A Short Answer:**

If you want to keep the new host name change, then you can create a `rabbitmq-env.conf` files in `/etc/rabbitmq` that references the old host name and all should be good. The following is what should be in the `rabbitmq-env.conf` file:

```
NODENAME=rabbit@OLDHOSTNAME
```

After adding the config file, restart the rabbitmq server then you should be good. (e.g. `service rabbitmq-server restart` (might need a `sudo` with ubuntu))

For more details you can read from the rabbitmq website: https://www.rabbitmq.com/man/rabbitmq-env.conf.5.man.html

**More Details About the Answer:**

I had a similar hostname issues using CentOS... The root issue was when rabbit installs, it references the current host name at the time of install. Since this is a rabbitmq thing, the solution should work for other linux flavors. If you want to see the full answer, you can see it at: [rabbtimqadmin - Could not connect: [Errno -2] Name or service not known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29501234/rabbtimqadmin-could-not-connect-errno-2-name-or-service-not-known/29502570#29502570)

Comment: This helped me. I updated to the latest version of rabbitmq (3.6.6-1) on ArchLinux and was unable to start it. Took a look in `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf` and 'lo and behold, the `NODENAME` was all wrong. Instead of `rabbit@machine`, it had become `rabbit@machine@machine` during the upgrade. A simple removal of the last `@machine` fixed the problem.

Comment: This is the proper answer IMHO...@Chewtoy it's even in the Arch wiki :-D https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Rabbitmq#Changed_hostname

Comment: So awesome!. Thank you. I changed my hostname and I didn't wanted to lose any information (usernames, etc). The env.conf file fixed my problem.

Comment: Where is this file on Windows?

Answer (score 6):

You could solve this problem by either deleting the erlang mnesia database associated with rabbitmq or reinstalling rabbitmq.

I got hint for first solution from [rabbitmq mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/rabbitmq-discuss/$20changing$20hostname/rabbitmq-discuss/PfqNVAkXi8M/31l1791aB8sJ). Excerpt from answer, `The Erlang Mnesia database is host specific (because it is a distributed DB). The simplest way to get you fixed is to clear out the database dir.`

The second method is the easiest way (not recommend though). 
To uninstall do

```
dpkg -P rabbitmq-server
```

You can refer this [link](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/install-remove-deb-package/) if you would like to know more about installing/removing debian packages.

Comment: How do you find the Erlang Mnesia Database?

Comment: Hi @MatthewCanty: I followed the second method.

Comment: @MattCanty At rabbitmq 3.6.9-1, just `rm -rf /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/`. And the Erlang Mnesia Database is under the file path of `/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/`.

Answer (score 5):

On Windows, the issue I was facing was due to the McAfee firewall. The exact error was:

> epmd error for host "<HOSTNAME>": address (cannot connect to host/port)

It started working as soon as I disabled the firewall

Comment: This helped me. been straggling with that for 2 hours,
Disabled it and worked like magic, Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Remove RabbitMQ database: `rm -rf /var/lib/rabbitmq/*`

This action solves the problem. I believe somewhere in dumps stored a record with correspondence of nodes host names and ips. This fact causes contradiction if some hosts changed unexpectedly.

Comment: Be careful while doing this. You will lose all data

Answer (score 4):

In my case I did not have a following entry in `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 <hostname>
```

where `<hostname>` is the hostname of my machine (as given by the `hostname` command). After adding that line, RabbitMQ started successfully. I did not have any earlier installations of RabbitMQ.

Comment: For me, this was the answer which worked. However I'm still puzzled why the default `127.0.0.1 localhost.localadmin localhost` line didn't resolve to the appropriate nodename. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

My solution was to check and correct the **`$HOSTNAME`** and `/etc/hostname`. It turned out that my router was a little confused and gave me a wrong hostname domain. After restarting this one, I called `export HOSTNAME=the.correct.hostname` and my rabbit runs without restarting the server os.

Comment: It worked, without even uninstalling rabbitmq-server

Answer (score 2):

When on Windows (sorry about that - I understand the topic is for Ubuntu) just reinstall the `RabbitMQ` service:

```
rabbitmq-service.bat remove
rabbitmq-service.bat install
```

The script is located at `C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-<version>\sbin` folder.

Or may be just changing the value of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Ericsson\Erlang\ErlSrv\1.1\RabbitMQ\@SName` is enough.

Clues: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/620

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, I changed my `/etc/hostname` file with the new hostname then restarted the machine. After that, I ran `rm -rf /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/*`

Then restarted the service : `sudo service rabbitmq-server restart`

At this point, it worked for me. If it still don't work, modify the file `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf` by adding those informations :

```
NODENAME=rabbit@YOUR_NEW_HOSTNAME
NODE_IP_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1
NODE_PORT=5672
```

Then restart the service : `sudo service rabbitmq-server restart`

Hope it helps.

Comment: I had similiar problem, rabbitmq had issues after i changed the hostname. And this worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and doing the steps Richard H Fung provided didn't helped me. I also had to uninstall these packages: `erlang erlang-epmd rabbitmq-server`

```
zypper remove erlang erlang-epmd rabbitmq-server
rm -rf /var/lib/rabbitmq/*
zypper install erlang erlang-epmd rabbitmq-server
systemctl enable rabbitmq-server.service
systemctl start rabbitmq-server.service
```

If you have another OS than openSUSE just use your package manager to remove these packages (e.g. `apt-get`)

Answer (score 0):

1. Change to old hostname.

   - sudo hostnamectl set-hostname (old_hostname)
2. Start rabbitmq-server and stop again.

   - sudo systemctl start rabbitmq-server.service
   - sudo systemctl stop rabbitmq-server.service
3. Change to new hostname.

   - sudo hostnamectl set-hostname (new_hostname)
4. Start rabbitmq-server.

   - sudo systemctl start rabbitmq-server.service

Answer (score -1):

The only solution which work for me: **install erlang & rabbitmq from deb**, so:

First remove:

```
apt-get purge rabbitmq-server
apt-get purge erlang
apt-get autoremove
reboot
```

After install wget:

```
sudo apt-get -y install socat logrotate init-system-helpers adduser
sudo apt-get -y install wget
```

Install erlang:

```
wget https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install erlang
```

Install rabbitmq:

```
sudo apt-get update
wget https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/releases/download/v3.7.17/rabbitmq-server_3.7.17-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i rabbitmq-server_3.7.17-1_all.deb
rm rabbitmq-server_3.7.17-1_all.deb
```

Answer (score -2):

Check qpidd daemon, it could be also already hogging the port that rabbitmq needs.

```
sudo netstat -lnp
```