# RabbitMQ wont cluster (nxdomain)

Tags: dns, rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl, epmd

I want to set up 2 rabbitmq servers to work in cluster. 
When when trying to run

`rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@my_rabbit_1.my.domain.name` on `my_rabbit_1`

I get `unable to connect to epmd (port 4369) on my_rabbit_2.my.domain.name: nxdomain (non-existing domain)`

I use `rabbitmq:latest` (debian), `.erlang.cookie` is the same, hosts resolve fine: I can `ping` both directions, `nmap -6 -p 4369 my_rabbit_2.my.domain.nam` returns `4369/tcp open  epmd`

EDIT:

`tcpdump` shows that while resolving hostname, `rabbit` or `epmd` performs not 2 types of DNS query: AAAA for IPv6 and A for IPv4 address, but only IPv4 which fails repeatedly with `nxdomain` as there is no IPv4 address available. However, it does not try AAAA DNS query, except when trying to run command like `rabbitmq -n rabbit@local.machine.domain.name`: then it runs AAAA query and outputs successfully. Hence the problem. How do I solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found solution that worked for me. [Erlang documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl) says that, by default, `-proto_dist` specifies a protocol for Erlang distribution, which defaults to `inet_tcp` (TCP over IPv4). So in IPv6-only environment you have to set `-proto_dist inet6_tcp` flag for `erl`.

This can be done by adding the following lines to your `rabbitmq-env.conf` (see [RabbitMQ configuration docs](http://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html)):

```
# For rabbitmq-server
RABBITMQ_SERVER_ADDITIONAL_ERL_ARGS="-proto_dist inet6_tcp"
# For rabbitmqctl
RABBITMQ_CTL_ERL_ARGS="-proto_dist inet6_tcp"
```

Note that `rabbitmqctl` and `rabbitmq-server` use different `erl` settings: I was unable to create cluster without `RABBITMQ_CTL_ERL_ARGS="-proto_dist inet6_tcp"` setting using `rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@host.in.my.domain`. It should not be necessary in production mode. Also note that [RabbitMQ configuration docs](http://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html) advice against using this setting except for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

> unable to connect to epmd (port 4369) on my_rabbit_2.my.domain.name: nxdomain (non-existing domain)

This is an error raised when the rabbitmq server is running on a hostname other than what you think it is running on, or when `hostname` doesn't resolve to what you think it does.

Amusingly enough I had this exact same issue last night when one instance in our cluster failed, came back on a new hostname, and somehow corrupted its internal authentication store etc.

Without the exact dns entries etc for your setup, all I can offer is general troubleshooting steps.

See [this StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14659335/rabbitmq-server-fails-to-start-after-hostname-has-changed-for-first-time)  question for a resolution that may help you - in particular the answer by Kishor Pawar.

Are you sure you configured rabbitmq to listen on IPV6?  Is there a reason you can't bind it to IPV4 as well on `127.0.0.1` for management operations?

Comment: `netstat -lntu` returns that epmd listens on both `0.0.0.0:4369` and `:::4369`, `rabbitmq` uses only IPv6 `:::5672`. Now I notice interesting fact: management ports are only IPv4, that's weird...

Comment: The reason I cannot use IPv4 is that environment I must use supports IPv6 only

Comment: The part that I cannot understand is when I inspect DNS capture with `tcpdump -i my_interface udp port 53`, I don't see any 'AAAA'  queries if I use `rabbitmqctl -n rabbit@host.in.my.domain status` or anything else. Actually, there's no 'AAAA' even when rabbitmq tries to connect to consul cluster! But when I try to `ping host.in.my.domain` or `nc -6vz host.in.my.domain 4369` there is 'AAAA' query and hostname resolution works fine